# how to filter nested list using Linq lambda

Tags: linq, entity-framework, lambda, linq-to-entities

I have a class person which has a list of addresses and phones as the follow code.
In my query I want a list of person but not including the address and phone that are already deleted, but is always returning all addresses and phones even they flag as deleted. How could I filter those nested lists using lambda?

```
public class Person{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }      
    public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Phone> Phones{ get; set; }
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
}

public class Address{
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }      
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }      
    [ScriptIgnore]
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}

public class Phone{
    public int PhoneId { get; set; }
    public string Number{ get; set; }      
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }      
    [ScriptIgnore]
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}

return GetDbSet<Person>()
    .Include("Address")
    .Include("Phones")
    .Where(i => i.Company.CompanyId == company.CompanyId)
    .OrderByDescending(o => o.CreateTime).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add conditions in your `Where` clause to exclude deleted address and phone like:

```
Where(i => i.Company.CompanyId == company.CompanyId &&
           i.Address.Any(r=> !r.Deleted) &&
           i.Phone.Any(r=> !r.Deleted))
```

Comment: But using this conditions if person doesn't have any address or phone the return will be null. In other words, what I want is return the person in any case but just bring the his addresses and phones that are not deleted...

Comment: The Code that I create was it...

`var person =  GetDbSet<Person>()
    .Include("Address")
    .Include("Phones")
    .Where(i => i.Company.CompanyId == company.CompanyId)
    .OrderByDescending(o => o.CreateTime).ToList();


if (person != null)
            {
                person.Address = person.Address.Where(c => c.Deleted == false).ToList();
                person.Phones = person.phones.Where(c => c.Deleted == false).ToList();
            }`