# Include filter child collection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

I have some difficulty to add some filter condition for included items in my LINQ query. My query is like

```
var item = _Context.Order.Include("Inner")
           .Include("Inner.first")
           .Include("Inner.second")
           .Where(x => ( !(x.IsDeleted) && (x.IsActive) && 
                 (x.itemid == id))).FirstOrDefault();
```

In the above code "Inner" is another list of item. Now i need to filter inner items. I only need inner item with filter condition inner.isDeleted = true.

Query should return a class like,

```
public class Order
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<InnerDetails> Inner{ get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

and InnerDetails class like

```
public class InnerDetails 
{
    public string Sample { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public int firstId { get; set; }
    public int secondID { get; set; }
    public First first{ get; set; }
    public Second second{ get; set; }
}
```

Can anyone suggest me a better approach to do this because i am new in LINQ and EF?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to filter - do you want to include only the entries from order.inner where order.inner.isdeleted, or do you want to remove the whole record eg the whole row of order that does not meet the condition? If it is the second one, what if you have 2 entries in order.inner, one where isDeleted = true and one where isDeleted - false

Comment: @Alex: I mentioned in the question like 'I only need inner item with filter condition inner.isDeleted = true.', ie i only need to include deleted inner record(inner.isDeleted = true). this is only for inner record and this will not affect outer record.

Comment: It seems you are trying to filter the nested list. I think this question may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25183685/how-to-filter-nested-list-using-linq-lambda and this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079378/how-to-filter-nested-collection-entity-framework-objects

Comment: What is Inner.first and Inner.second ??

Comment: Two different objects under InnerDetails

Comment: You should provide all the info when posting a question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Plus](http://entityframework-plus.net/)

EF+ Query IncludeFilter feature allows filtering related entities.

```
var item = _Context.Order
           .IncludeFilter(x => x.Inner.Where(y => y.IsDeleted))
           .IncludeFilter(x => x.Inner.Where(y => y.IsDeleted).Select(y => y.first))
           .IncludeFilter(x => x.Inner.Where(y => y.IsDeleted).Select(y => y.second))
           .Where(x => ( !(x.IsDeleted) && (x.IsActive) && 
                 (x.itemid == id))).FirstOrDefault();
```

Note: You cannot mix Include & IncludeFilter.

Wiki: [EF+ Query IncludeFilter](http://entityframework-plus.net/query-include-filter)

**EDIT: Answer sub-question**

> But we can achieve this using EF only

Yes, under the hood, my library uses a similar solution as projection

```
var item = _Context.Order.Select(x => new {
                Order = x,
                Inner = x.Inner.Where(y => y.IsDeleted),
                first = x.Inner.Where(y => y.IsDeleted).Select(y => y.first)
                second = x.Inner.Where(y => y.IsDeleted).Select(y => y.second)
            })
            .Where(x => ( !(x.IsDeleted) && (x.IsActive) && (x.itemid == id)))
            .FirstOrDefault()
            .Select(x => x.Order)
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

*Note: Code have not been tested*

**EDIT:** Answer comment

> I came across this issue in EF Core. Are you going to implement IncludeFilter also in the EF+Core version

Starting from the v1.10.0, the `IncludeFilter` is now supported in EF Core 2.x

See: [Release Note](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus/releases/tag/v1.10.0)

**EDIT: Answer sub-question**

> How can I ThenInclude after filtering

We do not have a `ThenInclude` yet.

So you need to use `IncludeFilter` again with all filter and navigate through the list or entity you want to include.

Comment: Can I ask do we need to add EF+ reference or what ?

Comment: Yes, you need to add in reference this library and add "using Z.EntityFramework.Plus" namespace to be able to use the IncludeFilter feature.

Comment: But we can achieve this using EF only. In my answer

Comment: Unfortunately IncludeFilter has many limitations, and I wasn’t able to make it working

Comment: I came across this issue in EF Core. Are you going to implement IncludeFilter also in the EF+Core version? ?

Comment: @JonathanMagnan 
How can I `ThenInclude` after filtering?

Comment: hi Jonathon , can you answer this question? Thanks, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62033907/c-filtering-on-theninclude-with-entityframeworkplus-includefilter also will IncludeFilter do the filtering in the database or filter after retrieiving the initial IEnumerable results? Just curious for SQL optimization, thanks

Answer (score -3):

You can achieve this in EF Core itself:

```
var item = 
ctx.Order.Include("Inner")
         .Select(x => x.Inner
                .Where(innerItem => innerItem.IsDeleted))
         .FirstOrDefault();
```

Or,

```
var item = 
    ctx.Order.Include(o=> o.Inner
                     .Where(x => x.IsDeleted));
```