# Filtering On ThenInclude, with EntityFrameworkPlus IncludeFilter

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-plus

I am trying to filter three child levels down and find only child elements where  PropertyMailingAddress.Status== True.

How do I convert filter three levels down and conduct nested filtering with EntityFrameworkPlus IncludeFilter? What is the most efficient way?

Class Structure is nested like this:

1. Property
2. PropertyParty
3. Party
4. PartyMailingAddress
5. PropertyMailingAddress  **<--- Status should equal true (Any grandchild PropertyMailingAddress nodes with Status == False, should be removed from this nested grandchild branch, keep the PropertyMailingAddress nodes which are True)**

This original way is not working:

```
var result = await db.Property.Include(pm => pm.PropertyParty)
                    .Include(pm => pm.PropertyParty)
                    .ThenInclude(x => x.Party)
                    .ThenInclude(x => x.PartyMailingAddress)
                    .ThenInclude(x => x.PropertyMailingAddress)
                    .Where(a => a.PropertyParty.Any(x => (x.Party.PartyMailingAddress.Any(z => z.PropertyMailingAddress.Any(h => h.Status == true))))).ToListAsync();
```

Trying efficient way with Entity Framework Plus:
Does the last line have to be relink joined again with nested wheres above, or is below fine?

```
var result = await db.Property.Include(pm => pm.PropertyParty)
                    .Include(pm => pm.PropertyParty)
                    .ThenInclude(x => x.Party)
                    .ThenInclude(x => x.PartyMailingAddress)
                    .ThenInclude(x => x.PropertyMailingAddress)
                    .IncludeFilter(y => y.PropertyMailingAddress.Where(z => z.Status == true)).ToListAsync();
```

*We will require all the nested entities, while filtering,

Currently using Net Core 2.2

Comment: Could you append your class definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot mixte `Include` with `IncludeFilter`.

In EF Core, the `IncludeFilter` should automatically add all paths.

We don't have the class definition so it makes it hard to know exactly the relationship but the query should look like this:

```
var result = await db.Property.IncludeFilter(pm => pm.PropertyParty
                                .Select(x => x.Party)
                                .SelectMany(x => x.PartyMailingAddress)
                                .SelectMany(x => x.PropertyMailingAddress.Where(z => z.Status == true)).ToListAsync();
```

The filtering is done in the database. So be careful with EF Core 2.x, as their have a client side evaluation they removed in EF Core 3.x which was causing some problem.

If you need more help, just provide a runnable solution in our issue tracker: https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus/issues

Comment: hi Jon, I will need the related entities, With the filter in the answer, your answer just contains the filter, thanks